# Why can't i catch this TimeoutException

Tags: dart, websocket, dart-html

I am currently building a Stomp WebSocket connection for Web where i want to control the connection timeout value. This is my connect method:

```
Future<WebSocketChannel> connect(StompConfig config) {
  final completer = Completer<HtmlWebSocketChannel>();
  final webSocket = WebSocket(config.url)..binaryType = BinaryType.list.value;
  var onOpenEvent = webSocket.onOpen.first;
  if (config.connectionTimeout.inMilliseconds > 0) {
    onOpenEvent = onOpenEvent.timeout(config.connectionTimeout);
  }
  onOpenEvent.then((value) {
    completer.complete(HtmlWebSocketChannel(webSocket));
  });
  webSocket.onError.first.then((err) {
    completer.completeError(WebSocketChannelException.from(err));
  });

  return completer.future;
}
```

and this is how i am calling it:

```
try {
    _channel = await platform.connect(config);
} catch (err) {
   print('Caught error');
}
```

Sadly i seem to be unable to catch the `TimeoutException` thrown by the `onOpenEvent.timeout(..)`. Instead it just prints this (seemingly uncaught exception):

```
Error: TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:59275/dart_sdk.js:5044:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:59275/dart_sdk.js:37476:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59275/dart_sdk.js:37472:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59275/dart_sdk.js:37332:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59275/dart_sdk.js:37338:13)
    at http://localhost:59275/dart_sdk.js:33109:9
```

What am i doing wrong? My previous code looked like this and worked for `TimeoutException`, but sadly not for any other exception thrown by the WebSocket:

```
Future<WebSocketChannel> connect(StompConfig config) async {
  final webSocket = WebSocket(config.url)..binaryType = BinaryType.list.value;
  var onOpenEvent = webSocket.onOpen.first;
  if (config.connectionTimeout.inMilliseconds > 0) {
    onOpenEvent = onOpenEvent.timeout(config.connectionTimeout);
  }
  await onOpenEvent;
  return HtmlWebSocketChannel(webSocket);
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* catch the exception, you just don't.
The statement

```dart
  onOpenEvent.then((value) {
    completer.complete(HtmlWebSocketChannel(webSocket));
  });
```

listens on the `onOpenEvent` future, and creates a new `Future` as result.
When the `onOpenEvent` completes with the timeout exception, this `then` invocation gets the error, and since it doesn't *handle* the exception, the future it returned also completes with the same exception.

Nobody ever touches that future since the statement above discards it, and therefore that future's result is an *unhandled error*.

The reason your previous code worked was that `await onOpenEvent` would *(re)throw* that error and make it the result of the entire `connect` call.

The new code does not have a way for that error to reach the `connect` function call, the `onOpenEvent.then(...)` future might complete after `connect` has returned.

You can try adding an error handler to the `then` call:

```dart
  onOpenEvent.then((value) {
    completer.complete(HtmlWebSocketChannel(webSocket));
  }, onError: (error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    if (!completer.isCompleted) completer.completeError(error, stackTrace);
  });
  webSocket.onError.first.then((err) {
    if (!completer.isCompleted) {    
      completer.completeError(WebSocketChannelException.from(err));
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I instead put a timeout on the `Future` of the `Completer` and return that future.